# ActionScript for stringOne and stringTwo

Tags: actionscript, for-loop

I have two strings. stringOne and stringTwo

I have code that I want to run for a variable named TXT

How can I do like...

```
for (stringOne and for stringTwo) {
TXT = stringOne (or) stringTwo;
...
stringOne or stringTwo = TXT;
}
```

Comment: Well everything inside of the FOR I want done to both strings, however I don't want to have to type the series if actions for each of them. I'd like to have a FOR statement so each string goes through the series of actions done to it. The first step in the series is setting a string named TXT as the value of whatever string it's currently on. The last step is setting the string it's currently on to the new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take those two strings in an array and use foreach to do some actions on the strings.

see this.

http://www.barklund.org/blog/2009/05/21/for-each-in-loops-in-actionscript-3/